# Adding the ability for a python Thread to report when finished

Tags: python, multithreading, logging

I am currently subclassing python's threading.Thread class in order to add additional logging features to it.  At the moment I am trying to get it to report both when the thread is started, and when it has finished.  Reporting the thread has started is easy enough since I can just extend the start() function.  However reporting exit has been more difficult.  I tried to extend the _bootstrap and _boothstrap_inner functions to add logging after they were complete, however that seems to have no effect.  I can not modify those functions at all.

Does anyone know of a way to add the ability for a thread to report that it has finished?

Comment: err [`thread.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join)?

Comment: can't you just put the notifying code at the end of run()?

Comment: As I see, the OP wants to create a custom `Thread` that will be subclassed by others later.

Comment: In a situation where I can't use thread.join() as making blocking calls causes issues with other parts of the system.

Comment: As @kirelagin said, I want something that can be subclassed later, as I am dealing with a fairly large system, and it would be rather inefficient/ineffective to expect every run() function to have logging added to the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the `target` function argument to the `Thread` constructor, so I'd do it this way:

```
class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, target):
        Thread.__init__(self, target=self._target, args=(target,))

    def _target(self, target):
        print "thread starting"
        target()
        print "thread ended"
```

Now, it does seem like you're used to using `Thread` the other way, by overriding its `run()` method, but maybe this will be of some use anyway.

Comment: Wow, I totally forgot about those arguments. Indeed, one can use a `_target` function which will call `self.run()`.

Comment: Hrmm, yah, we already have some fairly large objects that are subclassing thread already, so I am looking for a more OO way to do this.  Interesting way to do it in a slightly non OO fashion though.

Comment: And they say OO code is more flexible, reusable, and easy to extend.  Oh well!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your only option is requiring your users to override some other method instead of `run`. This way you'll have `run` in your `CustomThread` that invokes that other method and reports when done.

This has an extra benefit: `start` function is non-trivial, you'll be able to report successful start at the beginning of `run` instead of carefully dealing with overriden `start`.

Comment: Would work, yes... but that makes the expectation that noone will ever overwrite the run() function.  It just sets up for too many potential issues down the line for me to use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of asynchronous threads maybe you should consider a message queue for inter communication instead? have the thread post messages to an exchange and then exit. Then let the calling thread decide when to poll for messages. Kinda depends on your workload though.

This has the advantage that you can go multi process rather than multi thread if you want later.

I understand this suggestion may not be what you were wanted.